# Spring boot model class property validation

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to map a json object to a Spring boot model class now the contract says for a property it have only a certain set of allowed values(not more than 3).
Example:
Suppose that json has field "name" and the contract says allowed values for field "name" are john,todd,phil
Anything other than john,todd,phil wont be accepted.

Is there any way to achive this constraint using any annotations

Answer (score 0):

You can use following solutions

Solution 1:

Using @Pattern annotation with regex , if you want to use case insensitive use appropriate flags
@Pattern(regexp = "john|todd|phil", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)

Solution 2:
By creating a enum class type with allowed values

public enum {
JOHN, TODD, PHIL
}

In your model class use @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) on name filed